# How can I browse my search history in mps-youtube?

Tags: command-line, youtube

In [mps-youtube](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube) you can search for a song like this:

```
/song title
```

I would like to go through my search history to avoid having to retype my searches. Is this possible somehow? Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't know the program, but from [this issue](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/issues/504) it seems like there is a `history` command at least in the last version – maybe this helps? [This issue](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/issues/464) could also be interesting. If you're missing a feature and there is no issue addressing it yet you're free to [add one](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/issues/new) to let the developers know.

Comment: This `history` command is really cool and serving me for now. Do you want to put this as an answer which I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mps-youtube` provides a special command for that:

```
history
```